# Why is this intent not showing the jpeg correctly?

Tags: android, android-intent

So We have some code that opens an image via an intent.  We are using what ever image viewer is already installed on the users device.

It works on several devices except on the pixel C it won't display the image correctly.  I installed a file explorer and it can open the file correctly so the .jpeg is not corrupt.

Here is the code we use to open a new activity to show the image:

```
private void openExistingFile(@NonNull SalesMaterialFile file, @NonNull File target) {
   String extension = file.getExtension().toLowerCase();
   String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
   Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getString(R.string.provider_authority_fileprovider), target);

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

   // check if intent can be handled with current installed apps, if not open play store with search for app that can open the type of file selected
   if (IntentUtils.checkIntent(intent, getView(), R.string.no_app_for_file, R.string.find_app, view -> searchPlayStore("open " + file.getExtension() + " file"))) {
       startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that the image is not showing on the pixel C?

Comment: Is it really necessary to pass the image like that? I think you should pass the url and in the other activity get the image. Also, remember that through intent you just can pass 1Mb, if the image object is larger than that, you are gonna get an Exception.

Comment: @mikeescom We are passing the URI to the intent. (poorly named variable.  I'll fix that. )